# Check which server side method is being called

Tags: asp.net, xml, validation, server-side

How to know which server side method is called on button click. I am new and everything in the code is wrapped. So on

```
<asp:Button ID="Apply" runat="server onClick = "Apply_Click" .. >
```

And on the Button click function it just has>>

```
Apply_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     GetXML();
}
```

the GetXML method just generates the XML file.

But in click it actually validates the coupon entered and if it is correct than allows next page, else displays error. The GetXML() just prepares a XML file, it has no Stored Procedure call or any other method which may make this call of Validating the Coupon. 
Can anyone tell me how to see which server side method is being called to validate the Coupon.

If it is a custom method than how to see its code.

Comment: what is Coupon? Show Code for Validating Coupon

Comment: What other methods are in your page's class? Do you have `AutoEventWireUp="true"` anywhere?

Comment: Perhaps it's done using JavaScript, perhaps it's done in the Page_Load or any other page lifecycle event. You've got to read the source, place breakpoints and learn how to use your browser's debugging tools.

Comment: @Ganesh - that is exactly what i am trying to find

Comment: You mentioned server validation - are you sure it is server validation; if you turn javascript off; does the validation execute ?

Comment: yes, i checked for that and the coupon is validated without javascript enabled. so there is a server side validation. -@Ondrej Svejdar

Comment: Can anyone tell me how to debug the code while running so that to see which server side method is being called?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to execute validation with Apply_Click specify it:

```
<asp:Button ID="Apply" CausesValidation="false" runat="server 
    onClick = "Apply_Click" .. >
```

As for validation method, it can be any custom validator

```
<asp:CustomValidator OnServerValidate="magic_here" />
```

or custom javascript or Page_Load or Page_Init piece of code.

Comment: i want to know which method is validating the coupons, because on this Apply btn click i cant see any Validation code, just and XML file generated. Also, the XML file is not validating or calling any function to validate the Coupon. -@Ondrej Svejdar